# IntelliJ new settings sync

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-17

IntelliJ added in [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 EAP](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/09/intellij-idea-2017-3-eap-better-synchronization-of-your-settings-across-devices-and-other-improvements/?mail=newsletter&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTkRobFpqUTVPV0U0TWpWaCIsInQiOiI1d3U3alk5NUZLRG9QTVJBdVlJeTc4N3BrM2QycVBzZHBmZG1OR3RGdGNBZHR6VU5nMmlWaDhBVW5SQUJDR1ZmaWFqc3dybFRcL2FVS1ZSUDF1NzBoNFRKdkNnR1cxYXVaWmRHazkrVXFIcW9CSzA0Qlh0bFVlcWRoRlU1SnlRVDYifQ%3D%3D) an integration to store the settings configuration in their own store, instead of using a GitHub repo as I am doing now.

The only problem is that I can't find the "Gear Icon" in the "Status Bar" to set that in IntelliJ even if I am on:

`IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 EAP (Community Edition)
Build #IC-173.3531.6, built on October 31, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b6 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6`

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because this feature is only available in the Ultimate Edition

Comment: So the article saying "news in IJ 2017.3 EAP" is wrong?

Comment: The article is correct - the EAP covers both editions, and some of the features are only available in the Ultimate edition. This is actually mentioned in the announcement (The new plugin will in time be made available for all our paid products): https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/09/intellij-idea-2017-3-eap-better-synchronization-of-your-settings-across-devices-and-other-improvements/

Comment: Ok, thanks. I missed that this was only for Ultimate EAP.